# WKInterfaceSKScene to show SpriteKit debug information

Tags: sprite-kit, watchkit, watchos-3

I'm using SpriteKit on WatchOS and want to see the FPS, nodes and physics bodies.
However, the usual way of doing this is with UIView.showsFPS (etc.)
Under WatchOS, I don't have a view.
My structure is as per the default Apple structure:

WKInterfaceController
  -> WKInterfaceSKScene
    -> SKScene

ie. WKInterfaceSKScene is in place of the UIView and calling the scene but doesn't have a showsFPS value.

Is there a way to show the FPS etc?

(Trivia: the actual bug I'm trying to fix is with physics bodies of scaled shapes not contacting.  I understand physics bodies don't scale, but want to see exactly what is happening   - correction, they do scale, I had them in the wrong place.)

Comment: I'd still like to know if the information can be shown, but I've solved my problem.  I'm creating a custom class for each object, then I tick the box to make it a target for the iOS app as well.  Then in the iOS app view I can add the showsPhysics flag and do a few SKActions to move the object around.  Found out my physics body was not aligned with the shape.  Doesn't help me with the FPS though.